# transparent text div on top of parallax images

Tags: html, css

I am using a simple CSS parallax effect for 2 images and some text: when the page is scrolled a new image appears after the text passes.

However, I cannot apply transparency to the text-block div, as it appears to be adopting the body elements. Also, no matter how I style the text-block div it adopts a 100% width.

Is there a CSS solution to applying transparency and the div width, in this instance. I'd rather not use JavaScript, but if this is the only solution any thoughts are appreciated.

CSS:

```css
.body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.parallax1 {
  background-image: url("http://www.mrtsjewellers.com/images/image1.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.parallax2 {
  background-image: url("http://www.mrtsjewellers.com/images/image2.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.text-block {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parallax1"></div>

  <div class="text-block">
    <h1>Text Title</h1>
    <p>Lets put some text in here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="parallax2"></div>
</body>
```

HTML

```
<div class="parallax1"></div>            

<div class="text-block">
    <h1>Text Title</h1>
    <p>Lets put some text in here</p>
</div>

<div class="parallax2"></div>
```

Comment: Can you make this into an actual snippet? An example of the problem? I'm having a difficult time understand what you're doing and what the problem is.

Comment: can `.text-block` be a child of your parallax divs?

Comment: `<div>` elements are by design block-level elements. Even if it were transparent, it would take up space.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

Answer (score 0):

Thanks wlh you got the grey matter working. Small changes to .text-block get the desired effect.

css

```
.text-block {
    /*added*/
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:90%;
    left:15%;

    /*original*/
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    padding-left:10%;
    padding-right:10%;
    width:70%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your parallax images in your snippet, but just use `background: transparent;` on `.text-block`

```css
.body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.parallax1 {
  background-image: url("http://www.mrtsjewellers.com/images/image1.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.parallax2 {
  background-image: url("http://www.mrtsjewellers.com/images/image2.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.text-block {
  background: transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parallax1"></div>

  <div class="text-block">
    <h1>Text Title</h1>
    <p>Lets put some text in here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="parallax2"></div>
</body>
```